# Security Policy changes on EC2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to open up the MySQL (3306) port on my EC2 instance and even though I've added the rule, it appears the port is still closed. Do I need to reboot my instance for the policy changes to take effect?

Comment: When you added the rule, did you hit the 'Apply' button at the bottom of the table?

Answer (score 3):

No, SG changes do not require a reboot.

Are you sure you applied the SG changes after adding the 3306 rule?

To digress, I surely hope you're not opening up this port to the public internet. If so, please don't do that. Just use SSH tunneling if you need to access 3306 from outside the EC2 network.